# Reload Next JSON Data Grid ExtJS with Value from Ext Form

Tags: forms, window, extjs4.1

I'm trying to create grid data view from ExtJS with pagination. 
Actually there's no issue when I create a simple data grid. 
Then I want to create a "filter/search" function using Ext Form. 
It's only work for page one. Here is my Ext Form Code below :

```
var winFilter = Ext.create('widget.window',{
title   : 'Filter',
width  : 400,
height : 200,
modal  : true,
closeAction    : 'hide',
items  : frmFilter,
layout : 'fit',
bodyPadding: 5,
buttons:[
{
    text    : 'Filter',
    handler: function(btn){
        var win = btn.up('window');
        var form = win.down('form');
        tempProductID = form.getForm().findField('Product_ID').getSubmitValue();
        tempDescription = form.getForm().findField('Description').getSubmitValue();
        store.load({
            params: {
                start: 0,
                limit: itemsPerPage,
                productid: form.getForm().findField('Product_ID').getSubmitValue(),
                description: form.getForm().findField('Description').getSubmitValue()
            }
        });
        winFilter.hide();
    }
},
{
    text    : 'Close',
        handler: function(){
        winFilter.hide();
    }
}
]});
```

for the next page, my JSON return all data without using filtering value that I used before (Product ID and Description). 
Please if any advice

Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` (when used as an argument of `load` method) are applied only once. If you want to apply these params to each request you have to modify `proxy` [extraParams](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-extraParams) property:

```js
Ext.apply(store.proxy.extraParams, {
    productid: form.getForm().findField('Product_ID').getSubmitValue(),
    description: form.getForm().findField('Description').getSubmitValue()
}, {});
store.load();
```

Else you can use store [filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) method ([store.remoteFilter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-remoteFilter) should be set to true):

```js
store.filter([
    {property: "productid", value: form.getForm().findField('Product_ID').getSubmitValue()},
    {property: "description", value: form.getForm().findField('Description').getSubmitValue()
]);
```

But note that the filter part of request url has different form when `filter` approach is used. In this case filter part looks something like `?filter=[{'property':'productid','value':2}]&limit=10...`. Whereas when `params` approach is used url looks something like `?productid=2&limit=10...`. So when `filter` approach is used backend should parse `filter` property of request.